# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: not initiating request

Tags: ios, ios5

I have some code that looks like it should work which tries to send an Asynchronous request, but the request is never being generated:

Here is the function:

```
-(void) setEmail: (NSString *) subject andBody: (NSString *) body
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.my_url.com?";     

    // Create encoded query string
    NSString *query_string = @"subject=%@&body=%@";
    NSString *query_with_args = [NSString stringWithFormat:query_string , subject , body];     

    // Now encode the query
//    NSString *encodedQuery = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
//                                                                                           (__bridge CFStringRef)query_with_args,
//                                                                                           NULL,
//                                                                                           (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
//                                                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
//

    // Now concatinate url and query    
    NSString *final_url = [urlString stringByAppendingString:query_with_args];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:final_url];

    // Now send to the server    
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // TODO: ok I dont really understand what this is
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"......before request");

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {         
         NSLog(@"On return");

         NSLog(@"This is data: %@" , data);
         NSLog(@"This is response: %@" , response);
         NSLog(@"This is error: %@" , error);

         NSLog(@"OK");         
     }];        
}
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here and why the request is never sent? The logger with the

NSLog(@"......before request");   does get printed.

Comment: is the web service responding when you test it in cURL or something?

Comment: @mkral yeah it is working. But even if it wasn't responding, I'd still get a bad request or some sorts. no?

Comment: yea, you'd still get a response if it was bad request unless it's infinite loop. Have you tried looking into AFNetworking? It's simple to use and really useful.

Comment: `NSLOG` the `final_url` I have a feeling your `body` contains spacing and is confusing the server. try `url_ready = [final_url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: @mkral I tried it even without the encoding and it still didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.. You need to implement `NSURLConnectionDelegate` Protocol and methods in it.

```
NSString *final_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.my_url.com?subject=%@&body=%@",subject, body];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:final_url];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

Hopefully This one will help you.. http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/

Comment: your code worked, but when I tried this :    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) it still didn't work :(

Comment: You are adding that connection in a queue.But i dont know how to work with NSOperationQueue.So i have no idea to make it out with that code

Comment: should I maybe try to comment out the queue?

Comment: No.Not like that.It will add your operation into queue.May be it should call by yourself to make it execute.But i m just guesssing.Try yourself or go through the tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html